# Prevent environment variables to be forwarded via child_process.spawn

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

When, from a `parent.js` file, I run a

```
child_process.spawn('node', ['child.js']);
```

I get that all environment variables that were set in `parent.js` are also set in `child.js`. Now, while I know that I can add environment variables with the env property:

```
child_process.spawn('node', ['child.js'], {env: {newenv: 'newvalue'}});
```

How can I remove one? For example, say that some `process.env['parentonly']` environment variable is set in `parent.js`, and that I don't want it to be forwarded to `child.js` through the `spawn`. How can I do this?

I tried

```
child_process.spawn('node', ['child.js'], {env: {parentonly: /* anything like 0, false, null, undefined here.*/}});
```

But that doesn't work. If in `parent.js` I explicitly do

```
delete process.env['parentonly'];
```

then no `parentonly` is set in `child.js`, but that is slightly invasive.  Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way.
Create an object, clone the parent env to it. ( Define your own clone method, filtering out whatever property you don't want to copy from parent env)
Then pass the new object to child process as child env.